# how to divide children index in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, children

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".font-main-image").each(function() {
        childrenElements = $(this).find("img");
    });

    var num = childrenElements.length;
    var direction = 1;
    var i = 0;

    function toggle() {

        childrenElements.eq(i).toggle();
        i += direction;
        direction *= (((i % (num - 1)) === 0) ? -1 : 1);


    }

    var dir = 1;
    var j = 0;

    function toggleback() {
        childrenElements.eq(j).toggle();
        j += dir;
        dir *= (((j % (num - 1)) === 0) ? -1 : 1);
    }

    function int() {
        setInterval(toggleback, 90);
    }

    setInterval(toggle, 90);

    setTimeout(int, 90);
});
```

```css
img {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400 px;
    top: 0 px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="font-main-image">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-01.svg">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-02.svg">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-03.svg">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-04.svg">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-05.svg">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-06.svg">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-07.svg">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-08.svg">
</div>

<div class="font-main-image">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-01.svg">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-02.svg">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-03.svg">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-04.svg">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-05.svg">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-06.svg">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-07.svg">
    <img class="font-big-single-image" src="http://demo-studio.ir/reza/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ravi-08.svg">
</div>
```

I have few divs with same classes and and inside of them few img elements with same classes with display : none at my css and I want toggle between children(img elements with same class) from first to last and then from last to first and only have one display:block at a time so it will be some kind of animation. note that there are few divs with the same class and the img elements inside of them have the same class as well and I want to loop through every div separately.

Comment: Your code seems to work. I don't really get your question then :)

Comment: I want this code to run on each main  div children separately